# HOW GET data in ARRAY [] if i have 50 data in array i want to use parameter [0-3] and break to Query in sql

Tags: java, sql, arrays, servlets

array=[]
sent to servlet >>>>

```
///////// how i get [0]-[3] in array  value in array [0-50]
for(????)
{ var A = get[0].toString;
  var b = get[1].toString;
  var c = get[2].toString;
  var d = get[3].toString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the limited given information, If the question is how to processs an array which contains 50 objects with 4 untouched continuous objects sequentially

```
Object[] array = new Object[50];
//populate array
for(int i=3;i<50;i+=4) {
Object a = array[i-3];
Object b = array[i-2];
Object c = array[i-1];
Object d = array[i];
//variables may not be required as you can directly use array[i]
}
```

Comment: i will try it am newbie  i want use all data in array insert to     mydatabase [0-3, 4-7, 8-11,........]

Comment: as a side node, this will definitely create an `IndexOutOfBoundException` as at some point you´ll acces an index higher than 49 due to this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lists` class from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
Object[] array = new Objects[50];
//... somehow fill array with real data
List<List<Object>> parts = Lists.partition(Arrays.asList(array), 4);
for(List<Object> part: parts){ //List 'part' will always contain not more than 4 elements
    proccessPart(part); //passing elements to the method wich interacts with database
}
```